# Questions about increasing traffic - on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about attracting and retaining visitors to you site on-topic here?  I'm asking because of this [Internet Traffic Building](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28193/internet-traffic-building) proposal that just showed up on Area 51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would say it is on topic here and should be closed as a dupe (subset) of this site.